# watchOS 8: Siri Shortcuts cannot be activated by voice

Tags: siri, ios15, watchos-8

- My watch app supports Siri intents and it works under watchOS 7
- Under watchOS 8, Siri Shortcuts execute fine when invoked by the Shortcuts app on the watch
- Problem: under watchOS 8, I get the following message after triggering the Siri Shortcuts using voice:

[image]

Comment: Any update on this op? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem:

For the Siri Intent file: Make sure both the watch app and the Watch app extension is checked.

[image]